# How to organize REST API?

Tags: api, rest

I'm developing a rest API for our business system. We have the following resources so far:

```
/sales/orders
/sales/orders/{orderno}
/sales/order-items
```

There will be lots of resources when the API is finished, so we need to structure it in a good way to make it easy to understand. My question is: should `/sales/order-items` instead be `/sales/orders/order-items`? There is maybe no correct answer here, but what would you prefer?

One more question: The `sales/order-items` resource will list either all open items or all shipped items. It will *not* be possible to get all order-items regardless of status (open/shipped). The resource URI could the be like this `sales/order-items?orderstatus={OPEN/SHIPPED}` (the orderstatus query parameter would be *mandatory* then) or it could be two resources like this `sales/order-items/open` and `sales/order-items/shipped`. What is the preferred?

Comment: Just to be clear: under /sales/ there will be lots of resources in the end. Like /sales/customers, /sales/contracts, sales/quotes

Comment: It was a little unclear what the /sales/order-items resource actually is. It will give a list of all order-items regardless of the order it belongs to. To get only the items for a specific order there will also be a resource like this: /sales/orders/{orderno/items

Answer (score 1):

A resource is 'any information that can be named'. Your URIs should be entity based. 'order-items' is not an entity, but a data type.

`/sales/order/order-1456321` is the Entity you most likely want. Which would contain the data of all order items.

If you wish to restrict access, you can return a client error if no query string is supplied. and having

```
/sales/order/order-12345?status=open
```

etc. Hope this helps.

EDIT:

```
/sales/order-items or /sales/orders/order-items?
```

This is domain specific, and really should be answered by a domain expert. Your URI Hierarchy provides scope (and so detail) to your resource. So as an educated guess, It does not make sense to have "order-items" within the scope of "/sales/orders/" because "order-items" is not an "order".

```
/sales/ordered-items
```

seems the most sensible answer.

On a personal note, and not to question your domain too much, Having a strong understanding of the flow of the business and information that's stored may result in something along the lines of these suggestions;

```
/sales/orders?status=open - Are all orders shipped at once?
/sales/orders/order-1234/packages?status=open - Are orders split into packages?
```

Comment: I was not very clear about what /sales/order-items really is. /sales/orders/{orderno}/items will give all items for a specific order, but /sales/order-items will give a list of all order-items regardless of order. Then an order-item is an entity in the same way an order is an entity.

Comment: You may be correct. order-items is not an order, but order-items belong to an order. One order can have 1 to many order-items. Order-items can be retrieved using the sales/order-items regardless of the parent order. So I feel that it will not be completely wrong to place order-items under orders like this /sales/orders/order-items. The only reason I would like to place it under orders is to make  a little more structure to my API, so that everything that has to do with an order is found under /sales/order, but it may not be a good idea?

Comment: I dont fully understand your use-case, and so the nature of your "order-items". From my domain model i imagine, you would have a list of items in an order, and a "picker" (the person/role using your system) will fulfill (gather the items) and mark the item as fulfilled, and a "package" is "pending/shipped", and an order "pending/complete". What use, and to whom is a list of all items that need to be gathered?